# Проблема с SQL запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять в чем заключается проблема, есть вот такой sql запрос, который должен выдавать статьи только той категории, которая передана в запросе GET:    `

```
$cat = "SELECT d.id,d.cat,d.text,d.title,d.description,d.date,c.text,c.cat,c.titlecat FROM data d LEFT JOIN categories c ON d.cat = c.id WHERE d.cat = '$one'";
```

Вот собственно проверка входящего запроса:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {   $_GET['cat'] = $cats[$_GET['cat']];     $one = $_GET['cat']; }
```

Если вместо переменной $one в запросе написать цифру, которая соответствует категории новости, то все прекрасно работает, если оставить $one, то на страницу ничего не выводит. Проверил что содержится в $one через echo, вывело цифру, то бишь то что нужно, но почему в запросе воспринимается только цифра а не переменная, ведь значения одни и те же?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай вывод твоего SQL и ONE - по-любому у тебя в SQL вместо ONE - пустое место, т.е. если поставишь '', то ищет **d.cat = ''**, если кавычки убираешь, то SQl считает, что строка не завершена, т.е. **d.cat =**  - а чему оно равно? Проблема, скорее всего в проверке, к тому же - если у тебя cat не передается через GET, то чему он равен будет? добавь что-то типа:     **if ... else $one = 1;**
И в SQL неважно сколько пробелов, trim и прочая ерунда - это для нормального добавления, чтоб потом с поиском не париться, а для WHERE - сколько хотите их ставьте, главное чтобы пробелы не в самой строке были, т.е. можно: **WHERE id = 'много-пробелов 1 опять-много-пробелов'** - если id - число, но нельзя **WHERE name = 'много-пробелов Иван Иванович опять-много-пробелов'** - если name - строка

Answer (score 0):

уберите одинарные кавычки вокруг `$one`, если это число, а так же лучше сделать так:

```
$one = intval($_GET['cat']);
```

UPD:

А зачем такая белиберда:

```
$_GET['cat'] = $cats[$_GET['cat']];
$one = $_GET['cat'];
```

Не проще ли сразу:

```
$one = intval($cats[$_GET['cat']]);
```

Comment: Если убираю одинарные кавычки пишет что ошибка синтаксиса mysql. Переменной $one присвоил то, что вы написали, но пока без изменений.

Comment: В строке запроса ошибки не вижу...

@DemoS - кавычки это не ошибка

Comment: @Илья Карлеоне, обновил ответ

Comment: Проще, спасибо. Проблема осталась.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы попытаетесь выполнить следующее: `echo '$one'`, то интерпретатор будет считать '$one' строкой и выведет содержимое кавычек, а без них это переменная, которая содержит нужное вам значение, во избежание подобных ошибок изучите поподробнее  переменные и типы данных в PHP.

Comment: проверил так <?=is_numeric($one)?> , вывело 1, то бишь число всё правильно ведь.

Comment: какбы у ТСа в строка запроса в двойных кавычках так что то что вы написали не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к данной проблеме

Comment: проверте так <?=is_numeric('$one')?> !!!

Comment: пробовал, ничего не выводит

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно ничего против не имею, но Вам стоит читать какие именно ошибки выводит, и если уж не выполняется запрос - выводить то, как он будет выглядеть после инъекции переменных, а не сами переменные, затем тестировать его вручную.

Comment: И старайтесь избегать подобного синтаксиса - $cats[$_GET['cat']]. Ни к чему хорошему он не приведет.

Comment: Если проверить входящие данные и наличие такого элемента в массиве то лично мне непонятно к чему **плохому** это может привести? Разве что не совсем красиво :)

Comment: Я имел ввиду без проверки.

Answer (score 0):

ДУмаю, чтоит убрать пробелы между key=value.

```
$cat = "SELECT d.id,d.cat,d.text,d.title,d.description,d.date,c.text,c.cat,c.titlecat FROM `data` d LEFT JOIN categories c ON d.cat=c.id WHERE d.cat=".$one;
```

Попробуй такой запрос :)))

Answer (score 0):

а если trim(), вдруг пробелы закралис

Answer (score 0):

Джоин не верный...

```
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id=d.cat
```